# Adding number to label on swtichclick in titanium

Tags: android, titanium, addition

I am new to the scene and wonder how i am to go about this.
I have a switch that should add +1 or a "point" to a label when the switch is true.
and When it is false it should withdraw that same "point".

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
backgroundColor: 'white'
});

var view = Ti.UI.createView();

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'white'
});

var basicSwitch = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
 title: "+1"
});


basicSwitch.addEventListener('click',function(e){

});

 var label1=Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: ""

 });


view.add(basicSwitch);
win.add(view);
win.open();
```

My code so far,not much i know.

Comment: You want to add on which point?

Comment: I want to add "1" tio the label(which i left empty) if the switch is true.
I am going to add more swtiches later that does the same (adding +1 to label)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go first of all their are following errors in your code

1)Making window 2 times

2)Creating a label but not adding to parent container

3)Switch has change event listener instead of click one

4)You can set the switch title

and Here goes the correct code

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'white'
});
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.FILL
});

var basicSwitch = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
    top : 30,
    value : false,
});

basicSwitch.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.value = true) {
        label1.text = 1;
    } else {

    }
});

var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : ""

});
view.add(label1);
view.add(basicSwitch);
win.add(view);
win.open();
```

Thanks

Comment: That worked! thanks for helping a noob out.
You are a gentleman and a scholar